# How to split a CNN model into two and merge them?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to create two separate CNN models from a single CNN model. Let me name it as CNN-A and CNN-B.

i.e., Original CNN model = CNN-A model + CNN-B model

During the prediction, the raw input dataset are feed to the CNN-A. The output of the CNN-A are feed  as input to the CNN-B. The original output of the original model is the output of CNN-B model.

To implement the above architecture, I would like get your suggestions and idea if any, please?

Comment: I think the representation `Original CNN model = CNN-A model + CNN-B model` is confusing because CNN-A and CNN-B has distinct input/output pairs. From what I understood, this is what you want: `CNN-A` -> `CNN-B`, where `->` represents that the output of `CNN-A` becomes the input of `CNN-B`, and both the CNNs have their own input/output pairs. From a training point of view, this should be split into two independent tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation seems redundant. The reason is the input to each CNN should be an image. And let's say the output of the first CNN network is an image and you feed that to the second CNN, this is the same as stacking multiple convolution layers with additional dropouts and whatnot for the **One CNN model**.

So after all implementing a **deep** CNN will mimic the architecture you want.

You can also take a look at [transfer learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-with-convolutional-neural-networks-in-pytorch-dd09190245ce), which is able to utilize a pre-trained model's layers and you are capable to add your own final layers and make adjustments. This is also similar to what you are talking about.

================ After Comment =====================

You could use a model architecture like [mobilenet](https://towardsdatascience.com/review-mobilenetv1-depthwise-separable-convolution-light-weight-model-a382df364b69) for a model to be deployed on your mobile.

You could also apply transfer learning to existing pre-trained mobilenet models which will save a lot of time and resources.

Lastly, you could deploy the model(used for computers) on a server using Flask. Then create an API that will provide predictions when you send the relevant data to the server via a POST request. This is commonly used to reduce the load on mobiles and this the approach that I would prefer. This method is relatively efficient and is easily scalable.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and the link; my purpose is to deploy the CNN inference  for low power devices in a distributed way. i.e., after training a CNN model, I split the pre-trained model into two, A and B. Then, I deploy the  A  to run  in a smart phone and B in a server PC in order to make a prediction.  this set up is to reduce the computational workload of the smartphone. Any suggestion on this please?